# No funciona la barra de busqueda

Tags: html, django

no puedo hacer funcionar la barra de busqueda en mi codigo ahi adjunto los codigos, por favor necesito ayuda, ojala pueda ayudarme con esto de antemano gracias

[![form busqueda ]

```
        <form class="form-row " method="get" action="/paginas/busqueda/">
            {% csrf_token %}  
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="text" placeholder="Codigo Factura" name="q">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success"  type="submit"></button>
        </li>
        </form>
```

[![views]

````
    q = request.GET.get('q', '')
    fact = Factura.objects.filter(id__icontains=q)

    return render(request, 'paginas/busqueda.html',{'fact':fact})  ```






---

consulta el action estaria de forma correcta?, ya que todavia me sigue sin funcionar
````

{% csrf_token %}  
          
          
        
         ```

Comment: Hola, adjunta el código, no foto. O cerrarán tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Yo intentaria algo como esto

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Definimos la funcion
def busqueda_view(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    resultados = []

    if query:
       # Realiza la búsqueda y los vas almacenando en una lista
       resultados = TuModelo.objects.filter(campo__contains=query)

    return render(request, 'paginas/busqueda.html', {'resultados': resultados})
```

Espero te sea de utilidad